# How can I select rows that do not match corresponding rows in the same table?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, where-clause

I'm trying to figure out how to work out this query.

I have a table with multiple columns. Of these columns there are two: colA and colB.

The values in colA and colB in a row will match a different row in the same table, however the actual values in those columns will not be equal.

So for any row:

```
Col_A | Col_B
val1.0  | val2.0
```

there will be another row

```
Col_A | Col_B
val1.1| val2.1
```

There is an exception where this corresponding row does not exist and it is this row that I need to select.

Any help with the logic around this is greatly appreciated.

I've been working with queries of this type

```
Select * 
from table1 e 
where (e.Col_A = val1.0 and e.Col_B = val2.0)
and (e.Col_A != val1.1 and e.Col_B ! = val2.1)
```

is this even close? The above strikes me as I write it that if one clause is true then the other must also be true.

Thanks in advance for any help or hints.

Additional info as there were requests for clarification.

What I'm doing is updating a table. This table has a column that will catch and mark any exceptions to the rule I stated above.

The table has about 12 columns and two of these columns can have one of two possible values. Value Types for these two columns are varchar2(30) Normally for any row that has a set of values there will be another row that has the other values. Some of the other unrelated columns can be the same but not necessarily.

The code I have implemented is similar to below and is based on the left join suggestion from KAJ. However it seems to return too many rows in a straight query and in the update it actually updates every row.

```
Update TableA Set Col_Ex = ('Exception')
Where Exists 
(Select ... Example from Kaj s suggestion below);
```

Comment: You want the [`EXISTS`](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/EXISTS) predicate, or, to be more precise, its inversion, `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: Given you've already got 3 very different answers, can you clarify how the rows are linked (is it Col_A and Col_B or other columns)

Comment: Thanks for the very fast answers by the way, HopefullY i can clarify some of the questions. in the Table a row will have colA and colB. in one row if ColA has value 1.0 then ColB will have value 2.0; now that row will ideally have a corresponding row with value 1.1 and 2.1 respectively. Those are the only values that can exist. I'm working on finding those occasional times when the corresponding row does not exist. I'm going to get started on trying out the answers already. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the following:
1. The values are fixed (i.e. 1.0 to 1.1 and 2.0 to 2.1)
2. What you're looking for is the original row where the corresponding row does not exist
3. The join between original and corresponding rows is in the columns you haven't mentioned (I've called it key below)
... then something like the following should work:

```
select original.*
from table original
  left outer join table corresponding on corresponding.key = original.key and corresponding.Col_A = 'val1.1' and corresponding.Col_B = 'val2.1'
where original.Col_A = 'val1.0'
  and original.Col_B = 'val2.0'
  and corresponding.key is null
```

Comment: Your assumptions are all correct. I'm trying to implement this now, I have a syntax error but thats probably something on my end. Thanks for answering and I'll be sure to update later.

Comment: Well if you get stuck, provide more info on the tables you're using and the error you're getting and then maybe I/we can help further

Comment: I'm setting this as my answer. I have not yet been able to implement it yet. (I broke my toe so I'm delayed in my testing) I'm pretty sure it's some variation on this idea however.

Comment: Just a final update I was able to get the proper results by using a not exists in my update and excluded the join clause as I already ahd it in my update similar to this : UPDATE original A SET Colz = 'exception' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM corresponding B WHERE A.Key = B.Key and A.ColA LIKE B.ColA) Turns out ColB was a red herring and not vital to the query. I think this means I should mark Sam's as correct although I think both would work. Oh well thanks to all.

Answer (score 2):

```
Select e.*  from table e
where (e.Col_A = val1.0 and e.Col_B = val2.0) 
and NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table e2 
           WHERE e2.Col_A = val1.1 
           and e2.Col_B = val2.1 AND e2.key = e.key)
```

Comment: Thanks for responding I'm testing this one out curently but so far I don't receive any rows at all, I've been testing it where I know there to be three rows that should be returned. I still think this looks like what I need.

Comment: I think that the "NOT EXISTS" needs to be where the values are equal to val1.1 and val2.1 - because you've already got the negation.  Then you also need to be linking it back to the main row - Col_A and Col_B are *not* the joining columns (see dee's response to my list of assumptions)

Comment: @KAJ thanks for catching that, my fail in copy paste. Should be fixed. Will also attach the key comparison.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your values 1.0 and 1.1 are just one example of many.  Otherwise there would not be multiple records to look for.  Are you looking for values where A2 = (A1 + 0.1)?  If so, you could use something like this:

```
select t1.col_a, t1.col_b
from table t1
left join table t2 on 
    (t2.col_a = t1.col_a + 0.1 and t2.col_b = t1.col_b + 0.1)
where
    t2.col_a is null and t2.col_b is null
```

The LEFT JOIN will return null values when there is no record that meets the join criteria.